# Nuget package updated in a referenced project but still shows the old one

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a project `A` in visual studio which references another project `B` in the same solution.

The project `B` has a nuget package reference of another project `C`. I make some changes to project `C` and rebuild a pre-release nuget version of `C` and update the nuget package reference in `B` project. The project `B` properly shows the updated nuget version.

But, the project `B` showing up under `Project References` in `A` still shows the old nuget package version. I deleted and re-added the project reference `B` but without any success.

What I need to do to have updated nuget package in the project `B` under `A`?

Comment: Did all your projects target to net core new-sdk style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

When I update **Project C** from `2.0.0` into `3.0.0-beta1`, **Project A** and **Project B** are all the same version.

So for your issue, please try to delete `bin` and `obj` folder of **Project A** and **Project B**.

**Update**

The issue is that **Project A** also has a nuget reference of previous **Project C** which leads it always shows the old version of **Project C**.

Comment: Just now I have found the solution. It was actually because another nuget package reference in the Project A was also referring to previous version of nuget package of Project C. If I delete that nuget package, immediately Project B reference starting showing latest version of Project C nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And I have added your tips into my answer. You can check it and consider accepting it. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I had a reference to the package in three different projects.  To resolve it I removed the package reference from all the projects and then added it back in to all those projects.  Seems like it will hold on to old references.  Removing from all projects in one uninstall didn't work. I had to uninstall the package one at a time from each project until I removed it from all projects.